# Google Calendar API - Refresh Token - refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am reading calendar events successfully, but when the access token expires, I cannot refresh it. Up until now, I have been getting a new access token but this doesn't seem correct. I would rather refresh it properly.

I receive this error :

> refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken

From events.php

```
function GetEvents()
{
    $client = new \Google_Client();

    $credentialsPath = '/cfg/GoogleClientSecret.json';

    $client->setAuthConfig($credentialsPath);
    $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) 
    {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) 
        {
            $refreshTokenSaved = $client->getRefreshToken();

            /**** This line fails ****/
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refreshTokenSaved); 
            /*************************/

            $accessTokenUpdated = $client->getAccessToken();

            $accessTokenUpdated['refresh_token'] = $refreshTokenSaved;

            //Need to do more here once i have the new access token.
        }

        ReadThroughEvents($client);
   }
   else
   {
        $redirect_uri = 'oauthcallback.php';        
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
   }
```

oauthcallback.php

```
require 'google-api-php-client-2.4.0 2/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('/cfg/GoogleClientSecret.json');

$callbackuri = 'oauthcallback.php';

$client->setRedirectUri($callbackuri);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) 
{
   $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
   header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
else
{
     $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
     $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

     $redirect_uri = 'events.php';
     header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken should work assuming that the refresh token you are sending it is in fact a refresh token and not null or something.  I would try and print it out so that you can see its actually a value.

Here is my code.

## [oauth2callback.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/oauth2callback.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Oauth2Authentication.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client = buildClient();
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client = buildClient();
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); // Exchange the authencation code for a refresh token and access token.
    // Add access token and refresh token to seession.
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();    
    //Redirect back to main script
    $redirect_uri = str_replace("oauth2callback.php",$_SESSION['mainScript'],$client->getRedirectUri());    
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

## [Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    $client = getOauth2Client();

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
return $client;
}

/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed.
 * Example:  array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function buildClient(){

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access.  Will result in a refresh token
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
    $client->setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri());  
    return $client;
}

/**
 * Builds the redirect uri.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app#choosingredirecturi
 * Hostname and current server path are needed to redirect to oauth2callback.php
 * @return A redirect uri.
 */
function getRedirectUri(){

    //Building Redirect URI
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];                    //returns the current URL
    if(strrpos($url, '?') > 0)
        $url = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '?') );  // Removing any parameters.
    $folder = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/') );   // Removeing current file.
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $folder. '/oauth2callback.php';
}


/**
 * Authenticating to Google using Oauth2
 * Documentation:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Returns a Google client with refresh token and access tokens set. 
 *  If not authencated then we will redirect to request authencation.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {

        $client = buildClient();

        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }

        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {

            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 

            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I can see what I need to do - grab the refresh token when I first set the access token. But, it is not returning the refresh token. I think this is because, I have read this is only initially sent first time. I cannot find that post, but I think it was something about revoking access to the app. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: The refresh token is only returned the first time you authenticate a user.  You need to save it then.  Save it in a database or in a file its up to you.   To get one now you are going to have to revoke the users grant of access to your application and request it again.   You need the consent screen to popup again and ask you to grant access to their calendar account.

Comment: How do I revoke the users access? Is this in https://console.developers.google?
Thanks

Comment: It OK - I have managed to get a refresh Token. I am storing it, now need to wait for my access token to expire to test. If it all works, I will be sure to mark as answered. Thanks for your help.